# Magento | How i can add a product in shopping cart in a custom module?

Tags: php, rest, magento

I am currently working on the development of a management module Cart on Magento 1.9

I'm stuck on adding a product to my cart (I tried many different things) and that's why I solicits your help.

My module extends the rest API of magento and I have already managed update to my cart (quantity of products) but now I'll wish to add a new product via the POST method.
Of course I'm logged as customer. I defined the creation privileges for this role. (I can do the update without problems)

Here is my code :

```
protected function _create(array $data){

    $store = $this->_getStore();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store->getId());

    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();

    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(4);


    // Add product to cart
    $cart->addProduct($productCollection,
        array(
            'product_id' => $productCollection->getId(),
            'qty' => '1'
        )
    );
    // Save cart
    $cart->save();

}
```

In this simple example, I try to add the product id 4 in quantity 1.
My problem is that I have no error in the log, and everything seems to be past. But when I get my cart, there is no product to add...

in return I have a code 200 OK

Do you have any suggestions to help me?

Thanks a lot for your help

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution after traveling all internet;)

In fact when you want to reach the cart before checkout, magento uses the definition "Quote" ... Not easy to understand  for a beginner on Magento....
So in order to facilitate research of those who are like me had troubles, here is my code to add a new product in the cart (before checkout) :

```
//$data['entity_id'] = The id of the product you want to add to the cart
//$data['qty'] = The quantity you want to specify

protected function _create(array $data)
{
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store->getId());

    // Get Customer's ID
    $customerID = $this->getApiUser()->getUserId();

    // Load quote by Customer
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
             ->loadByCustomer($customerID);

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         // set the current store ID
                         ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                         // load the product object
                         ->load($data['entity_id']);

    // Add Product to Quote
    $quote->addProduct($product,$data['qty']);

    try {
        // Calculate the new Cart total and Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_error($e->getMessage(),Mage_Api2_Model_Server::HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    }

}
```

I hope this can help someone

Regards

Carniflex

Comment: Hi! I want to make rest api's for adding products but here you are not using any id's of user. Do you have any idea how to make rest api for this.

Comment: Hi!

It's pretty simple.
If you look closely I load the "quote" by "customer" :

`// Load quote by Customer
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
             ->loadByCustomer($this->getApiUser()->getUserId());`

If you have the "customerId", you can load the model "customer" with this ID

`$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);`

And so load the "quote" by "customer" :

`$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
             ->loadByCustomer($customer);`

I hope it'll help you

Regards